# Understanding the use of CONST within Looped Array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hashtable

My questions is about how CONST variable is used in this code.

Why does this code work if CONST variables cannot be reassigned?

I understand that as it is looping it is reassigning the value of "firstNumber". Is that correct?

or

Is it because of the way it is looping that it is not being treated as a reassignment but as a redeclaration?

**I'm new to asking questions about code, I apologize **

```js
function twoNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  // loop through array and assign index 0 to firstNumber
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const firstNumber = array[i];
    // loop through array and assign index 1 to secondNumber
    for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      const secondNumber = array[j];

      // create condition that adds index 0 + 1 to see if it is equals to targetSum
      if ( firstNumber + secondNumber === targetSum ) {
        return [firstNumber, secondNumber];
      }
    }
  }
  return []
}

console.log(twoNumberSum([3,5,-4,8,11,1,-1,6],10));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CODE SANDBOX</title>
</head>
<body>
This is Code SandBox.
</body>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A `const` variable is scoped to its enclosing block. Each time the block is re-entered, a new variable is created; the previous one ceases to exist.

Comment: And in case of actual variables (non-constant values) you could use `let` instead of `var` (for example in those loops), because `var` is a bit more error-prone (it uses different hoisting rules than `let` and `const`). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#variable_hoisting

Answer (score 1):

The `const` keyword declares a variable with a constant reference to a value. In your example code, the `const` variable is scoped to its `for` block. On every iteration, the `for` loop terminates and creates a new enclosing scope, `firstNumber` is "garbage collected", and declared again(not a *redeclaration*, but rather a *recreation*) on each subsequent step.

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside a loop gets redeclared each iteration